# How to get average from two columns in csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with 2 columns

```
rw1, 24
rw2, 34
rw3, 56
rw1, 78
rw2, 56
rw2, 45
rw2, 64
rw3, 32
rw1, 28
```

Now i want to have average.py file which calculates average of all rw1, rw2 and rw3 respectively and write that to average.txt file

```
rw1 - average value,
rw2 - average value, 
rw3 - average value
```

Comment: Please post your attempt to solve the problem and explain why it isn't sufficient.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html and with a loop you can calculate your averages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given read csv and convert them to tuple. then `sort` them to use in `Groupby`

```
import itertools
import csv

fileLocation = 'newslot.csv'
with open(fileLocation,'rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    lis=sorted([(i[0],i[1]) for i in r])
    for k,g in itertools.groupby(lis,key=lambda x:x[0]):
        g=list(g)
        print k,sum(int(i[1]) for i in g)/len(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

With [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it's kind of short :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)

In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
     0   1
0  rw1  24
1  rw2  34
2  rw3  56
3  rw1  78
4  rw2  56
5  rw2  45
6  rw2  64
7  rw3  32
8  rw1  28

In [2]: df.groupby(df[0]).mean() # it groups on the column "0", and calculates the mean on the different group 
Out[2]: 
             1
0             
rw1  43.333333
rw2  49.750000
rw3  44.000000
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

def avg(lst):
    return sum(map(float, lst)) / len(lst)

def avgcsv(filename, k=0, v=1):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = sorted(csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True), key=itemgetter(k))
    return ['%s - %g' % (name, avg(map(itemgetter(v), group)))
            for name, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(k))]

with open('average.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(',\n'.join(avgcsv('filename', 0, 1)))
```

*Output*

```
rw1 - 43.3333,
rw2 - 49.75,
rw3 - 44
```

Comment: have you converted the string to integer?

Comment: and you missed a final brace at last i think :)